# Do you think it is necessary to mark id fields with insertable = false and updatable = false?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Do you think it is necessary to mark id fields with insertable = false and updatable = false ?

I haven't seem much people doing this before, but today I checked one code that used these properties setted to false for an id field.

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not at all. It depends whether you really don't want that field to persist. In the mentioned case of an `id`, I assume it a `primary key` for that entity. So, I can think of `updatable = false` for an `id`, but `insertable = false` is unlikely. You need to check how its configured otherwise to provide the value for that during `insert`.

Read the [Java docs](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html) to get better understanding, there is no other better substitute.